# Why can't I subclass datetime.date?

Tags: python, oop, datetime, subclass

Why doesn't the following work (Python 2.5.2)?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> class D(datetime.date):
        def __init__(self, year):
            datetime.date.__init__(self, year, 1, 1)
>>> D(2008)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

I wanted to create a class that was just like `datetime.date`, but with a different `__init__` function.  Apparently my function never gets called.  Instead the original `datetime.date.__init__` is called and fails because that expects 3 arguments and I am passing in one.

What's going on here?  And is this a clue?

```
>>> datetime.date.__init__
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
```

Thanks!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309129/why-cant-i-inherit-from-dict-and-exception-in-python

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Regarding several other answers, this doesn't have anything to do with dates being implemented in C per se.  The `__init__` method does nothing because they are *immutable* objects, therefore the constructor (`__new__`) should do all the work.  You would see the same behavior subclassing int, str, etc.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> class D(datetime.date):
        def __new__(cls, year):
            return datetime.date.__new__(cls, year, 1, 1)


>>> D(2008)
D(2008, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 12):

Please read the Python reference on [*Data model*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), especially about the `__new__` [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Excerpt from that page (my italics):

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of *immutable* types (like int, str, or tuple) to *customize instance creation*. It is also commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class creation.

`datetime.datetime` is also an immutable type.

PS If you think that:

- an object implemented in C cannot be subclassed, or
- `__init__` doesn't get called for C implemented objects, only `__new__`

then please try it:

```
>>> import array
>>> array
<module 'array' (built-in)>
>>> class A(array.array):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(array.array, self).__init__(*args)
        print "init is fine for objects implemented in C"

>>> a=A('c')
init is fine for objects implemented in C
>>>
```

Comment: Upvoted, because this seems the only answer on SO with a documentation link. But your example is broken. It only works because the initializer is an optional argument. Try `a=A('c',[],5,8)`!

Comment: `>>> a=array.array('c', [], 5, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: array() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
>>> a=A('c', [], 5, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: array() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)`
What would be a non-broken example? @mkiever

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer, and a possible solution (use a function or strptime instead of subclassing)

http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg192783.html

Comment: Thank you, the link to the problem is right on the money, but there is not an explanation __why__ it didn't work.  What's the root of the problem and can it be overcome?

Answer (score 2):

You're function isn't being bypassed; Python just never gets to the point where it would call it. Since datetime is implemented in C, it does its initialization in `datetime.__new__` not `datetime.__init__`. This is because datetime is immutable. You could presumably get around this by overriding `__new__` instead of `__init__`. But as other people have suggested, the best way is probably not subclassing datetime at all.

Comment: @Benjamin: Please check my answer, and consider correcting yours, since it's the most voted so far; basically, only your last sentence could be considered helpful; the others are misinformed/ing. Also, please fix your "it's"​→"its" and "(Not"​→"(Note".

Answer (score 1):

You can **wrap** it and add extended functionality to your wrapper.

Here is an example:

```
class D2(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.date_object = datetime.date(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.date_object, name)
```

And here is how it works:

```
>>> d = D2(2005, 10, 20)
>>> d.weekday()
3
>>> dir(d)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__',
 '__weakref__', 'date_object']
>>> d.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
'20.10.2005'
>>>
```

Note that `dir()` doesn't list `datetime.date`s attributes.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: You are right. It is actually subclassable. I will go back to docs and find out where I made this mistake. Meanwhile I'm fixing the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a factory function instead of creating a subclass:

```
def first_day_of_the_year(year):
  return datetime.date(year, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's cool, but I am curious as to why the subclassing does not work (how it being an extension class makes the difference) and whether this can be overcome...