# Seemingly trivial issue calling int's __init__ in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Observe the following code:

```
class Angle(int):
    """Basic Angle object: Angle(number)"""

    def __init__(self, angle):
        angle %= 360
        super(Angle, self).__init__(angle)
```

Fairly simple stuff, `Angle` is basically just an `int` that never goes above 360 or below 0. This `__init__` just makes sure that the input angle matches the conditions listed prior. But for some reason the above code gives me the following output:

```
>>> a = Angle(322)
>>> a
322
>>> b = Angle(488)
>>> b
488
```

Why on earth would this be happening? The code seemed so trivial to me, but maybe I'm just missing something really obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: extending int and MRO for \_\_init\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184337/python-extending-int-and-mro-for-init)

Comment: Okay, thanks, adding a custom `__new__` magic method cleared up the problem completely and maintains the rest of the code quite nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be overriding `__new__` for immutable classes like int

```
class Angle(int):
  def __new__(cls, val):
    val %= 360
    inst = super(Angle, cls).__new__(cls, val)
    return inst
```

see [python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Consult [**new**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method of python's object interface.

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also
>   commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class
>   creation.