# Subclassing datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime, subclass, python-datetime

I'm looking into creating a python datetime-subclass which provides a default timezone when created.

For the sake of keeping this question simple, let's assume I *always* want to hard-code my datetimes to be in UTC.

I can't figure out why the following works:

```
import datetime, dateutil.tz

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['tzinfo'] = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
    return datetime.datetime(*args, **kwargs)
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
class Foo(datetime.datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['tzinfo'] = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Running the first method gives me the datetime object I expect:

```
>>> foo(2012, 11, 10)
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> foo(2012, 11, 10).tzinfo is None
False
```

But creating an instance of the Foo class doesn't seem to set the tzinfo object.

```
>>> Foo(2012, 11, 10)
Foo(2012, 11, 10, 0, 0)
>>> Foo(2012, 11, 10).tzinfo is None
True
```

Any ideas of what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you sir, you are correct. Since datetimes are immutable, the  extra logic should be placed in __new__ rather than __init__.

Answer (score 3):

Providing the solution, as explained in [Why can't I subclass datetime.date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399022/why-cant-i-subclass-datetime-date) for the sake of completeness, thanks to [dano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073595/dano) for the link.

The extra functionality has to be implemented in new since the datetime object is immutable:

```
class Foo(datetime.datetime):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['tzinfo'] = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
        return datetime.datetime.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```