# __cinit__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments when extending a Cython class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, runtime-error, subclass, cython

I want to extend scikit-learn's `ClassificationCriterion` class which is defined as a Cython class in an internal module [`sklearn.tree._criterion`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx). I would like to do that in Python, as normally I don't have access to the pyx/pxd files of sklearn (so I cannot `cimport` them). However, when I try to extend `ClassificationCriterion`, I get the error `TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given)`. The below MWE reproduces the error, and shows that the error occurs after `__new__` but before `__init__`.

Is there any way to extend a Cython class like this?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree._criterion import ClassificationCriterion

class MaxChildPrecision(ClassificationCriterion):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('new')
        super().__new__(MaxChildPrecision, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('init')
        super(MaxChildPrecision).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion=MaxChildPrecision())
```

Comment: Methods need to take self as the first positional argument. But they shouldn't pass it on the super call, which is why it's necessary to capture it outside `*args`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, I updated the code, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: [You need to define `__new__`, not `__cinit__`.](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init)

Comment: @user2357112 thanks to you too. I updated the code, but this does not resolve the problem yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to define `__new__` *and pass the superclass `__new__` the arguments it expects*. Same with passing the superclass `__init__` the arguments it expects ([although those arguments might not be the ones you expect it to expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390372/why-cant-i-subclass-tuple-in-python3)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There two issues. Firstly, [`ClassificationCriterion` requires two specific arguments to its constructor that you aren't passing it](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx#L218). You will have to work out what these arguments represent and pass them to the base class.

Secondly, there's a Cython issue. If we look at [the description of how to use `__cinit__`](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html) then we see:

> Any arguments passed to the constructor will be passed to both the `__cinit__()` method and the `__init__()` method. If you anticipate subclassing your extension type in Python, you may find it useful to give the `__cinit__()` method `*` and `**` arguments so that it can accept and ignore extra arguments. Otherwise, any Python subclass which has an **init**() with a different signature will have to override `__new__()` as well as `__init__()`

Unfortunately, the writers of sklearn didn't provide `*` and `**` arguments, so you do have to override `__new__`. Something like this should work:

```
class MaxChildPrecision(ClassificationCriterion):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        # I have NO IDEA if these arguments make sense!
        return super().__new__(cls,n_outputs=5,
                           n_classes=np.ones((2,),dtype=np.int))
```

I pass the necessary arguments to `ClassificationCriterion` in `__new__` and deal with the rest in `__init__` as I see fit. I don't need to call the base class `__init__` (because the base class doesn't define `__init__`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope that this did not cost you too much time, because as you posted it I had *almost* arrived at the same result, but wasn't ready to post an answer yet. It seems that the correct parameters for my case are `n_outputs=1, n_classes=np.array([2], dtype=np.intp)`. When I subclass in Python and override `node_impurity` and `children_impurity`, they don't get called. Am I correct in thinking that is because these methods are `cdef`s and not `cpdef`s? I'm now subclassing in Cython and that seems to work OK.

Comment: Yes - you can't access `cdef` methods in Python. It sounds like subclassing in Cython is the way to go if you need to access them.

Comment: (2/2) As a side not / for future reference: I added [a feature request to scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10251) to make the extension of criteria more straightforward. I will post my code there once it works properly, such that this answer can be the correct answer here and future readers can look there for the scikit-learn peculiarities.