# Difference between __getattr__ and __getattribute__

Tags: python, getattr, getattribute

I am trying to understand when to define `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`.  The [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#object.__getattribute__) mentions `__getattribute__` applies to new-style classes. What are new-style classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the difference between \_\_getattr\_\_ and \_\_getattribute\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute)

Comment: @Trilarion yet that question mentions an answer from here...

Answer (score 680, accepted):

A key difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` is that `__getattr__` is only invoked if the attribute wasn't found the usual ways.  It's good for implementing a fallback for missing attributes, and is probably the one of two you want.

`__getattribute__` is invoked before looking at the actual attributes on the object, and so can be tricky to implement correctly.  You can end up in infinite recursions very easily.

New-style classes derive from `object`, old-style classes are those in Python 2.x with no explicit base class.  But the distinction between old-style and new-style classes is not the important one when choosing between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

You almost certainly want `__getattr__`.

Comment: Can I implement both of them in the same class? If I can, what is it for implementing the both?

Comment: @Alcott: you can implement them both, but I'm not sure why you would.  `__getattribute__` will be called for every access, and `__getattr__` will be called for the times that `__getattribute__` raised an `AttributeError`.  Why not just keep it all in one?

Comment: @NedBatchelder, if you want to (conditionally) override calls to existing methods, you would want to use `__getattribute__`.

Comment: "In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation should always call the base class method with the same name to access any attributes it needs, for example, object.__getattribute__(self, name)."

Comment: @kmonsoor. That's a good reason to implement both. `objec.__getattribute__` invokes `myclass.__getattr__` under the right circumstances.

Comment: Just a note: to access a variable within `__getattribute__` without invoking infinite recursion, `super().__getattribute__(item)` must be called

Comment: I have this worry, is there any disadvantage to directly using super().__getattribute__(item), because more resources online suggestion object.__getattribute__(item) (even the Python official documentation used the base class object attribute access directly ). I would think that it makes more sense to use super since this attribute customization might be implemented by a parent class and using super simply skips their access

Answer (score 244):

Lets see some simple examples of both `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` magic methods.

### `__getattr__`

Python will call  `__getattr__` method whenever you request an attribute that hasn't already been defined. In the following example my class **Count** has no `__getattr__` method. Now in main when I try to access both `obj1.mymin` and `obj1.mymax` attributes everything works fine. But when I try to access `obj1.mycurrent` attribute -- Python gives me `AttributeError: 'Count' object has no attribute 'mycurrent'`

```
class Count():
    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)
print(obj1.mymax)
print(obj1.mycurrent)  --> AttributeError: 'Count' object has no attribute 'mycurrent'
```

Now my class **Count** has `__getattr__` method. Now when I try to access  `obj1.mycurrent` attribute -- python returns me whatever I have implemented in my `__getattr__` method. In my example whenever I try to call an attribute which doesn't exist, python creates that attribute and sets it to integer value 0.

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax    

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__dict__[item]=0
        return 0

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)
print(obj1.mymax)
print(obj1.mycurrent1)
```

### `__getattribute__`

Now lets see the `__getattribute__` method. If you have  `__getattribute__` method in your class,  python invokes this method for every attribute regardless whether it exists or not. So why do we need `__getattribute__` method? One good reason is that you can prevent access to attributes and make them more secure as shown in the following example.

Whenever someone try to access my attributes that starts with substring **'cur'** python raises `AttributeError` exception. Otherwise it returns that attribute.

```
class Count:

    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax
        self.current=None
   
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return object.__getattribute__(self,item) 
        # or you can use ---return super().__getattribute__(item)

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)
print(obj1.mymax)
print(obj1.current)
```

Important: In order to avoid infinite recursion in `__getattribute__` method, its implementation should always call the base class method with the same name to access any attributes it needs. For example: `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` or  `super().__getattribute__(item)` and not `self.__dict__[item]`

### IMPORTANT

If your class  contain both **getattr** and **getattribute** magic methods then  `__getattribute__` is called first. But if  `__getattribute__` raises
`AttributeError` exception then the exception will be ignored and `__getattr__` method will be invoked. See the following example:

```
class Count(object):

    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax
        self.current=None

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__dict__[item]=0
        return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return object.__getattribute__(self,item)
        # or you can use ---return super().__getattribute__(item)
        # note this class subclass object

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)
print(obj1.mymax)
print(obj1.current)
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly would be use case for overriding `__getattribute__` but surely this isn't. Because per your example, all you are doing in `__getattribute__` is raising `AttributeError` exception if the attribute isn't there in `__dict__` of the object; but you don't really need this because this is default implementation of `__getattribute__` and infact `__getattr__` is exactly what you need as a fallback mechanism.

Comment: @Rohit `current` is defined on instances of `Count` (see `__init__`), so simply raising `AttributeError` if the attribute isn't there isn't quite what's happening - it defers to `__getattr__` for _all_ names starting 'cur', including `current`, but also `curious`, `curly` ...

Answer (score 21):

This is just an example based on [Ned Batchelder's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278104/3798217).

`__getattr__` example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print "looking up", attr
        value = 42
        self.__dict__[attr] = value
        return value

f = Foo()
print f.x 
#output >>> looking up x 42

f.x = 3
print f.x 
#output >>> 3

print ('__getattr__ sets a default value if undefeined OR __getattr__ to define how to handle attributes that are not found')
```

And if same example is used with `__getattribute__` You would get >>> `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: **Actually, this is terrible.** Real-world `__getattr__()` implementations  only accept a finite set of valid attribute names by raising `AttributeError` for invalid attribute names, thereby avoiding [subtle and difficult-to-debug issues](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/52238-__getattr__-handle-with-care). This example unconditionally accepts _all_ attribute names as valid – a bizarre (and frankly error-prone) misuse of `__getattr__()`. If you want "total control" over attribute creation as in this example, you want `__getattribute__()` instead.

Comment: @CecilCurry: All the issues that you linked to involve implicitly returning None rather than a value, which this answer doesn't do. What's wrong with accepting all attribute names? It's the same as a `defaultdict`.

Comment: The problem is that `__getattr__` will be called *before* superclass lookup. This is OK for a direct subclass of `object`, since the only methods you really care about there are magic methods that ignore the instance anyway, but for any more complex inheritance structure, you completely remove the ability to inherit anything from the parent.

Comment: @Simon K Bhatta4ya, your last print statement is a comment. Right? It's a long line and tedious to read (One has to scroll a lot in the right side). What about putting the line after the code section? Or if you want to put it in the code section, I think it would  be better to break it into two different lines.

Comment: Note that in `f.x = 3`, `__getattr__()` is not called, but `__setattr__()` is.  In this case, since it's not implemented, the default version is inherited from `object`.

Answer (score 16):

New-style classes inherit from `object`, or from another new style class:

```
class SomeObject(object):
    pass

class SubObject(SomeObject):
    pass
```

Old-style classes don't:

```
class SomeObject:
    pass
```

This only applies to Python 2 - in Python 3 all the above will create new-style classes.

See *[9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)* (Python tutorial), [NewClassVsClassicClass](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) and *[What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)* for details.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? Lol

Answer (score 7):

New-style classes are ones that subclass "object" (directly or indirectly).  They have a `__new__` class method in addition to `__init__` and have somewhat more rational low-level behavior.

Usually, you'll want to override `__getattr__` (if you're overriding either), otherwise you'll have a hard time supporting "self.foo" syntax within your methods.

Extra info: http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/31482/0/page/4

Answer (score 6):

- **getattribute**: Is used to retrieve an attribute from an instance. It captures every attempt to access an instance attribute by using dot notation or getattr() built-in function.
- **getattr**: Is executed as the last resource when attribute is not found in an object. You can choose to return a default value or to raise AttributeError.

Going back to the **__getattribute__** function; if the default implementation was not overridden; the following checks are done when executing the method:

- Check if there is a descriptor with the same name (attribute name) defined in any class in the MRO chain (method object resolution)
- Then looks into the instance’s namespace
- Then looks into the class namespace
- Then into each base’s namespace and so on.
- Finally, if not found, the default implementation calls the fallback **getattr**() method of the instance and it raises an AttributeError exception as default implementation.

This is the actual *implementation* of the object.__getattribute__ method:

> .. c:function:: PyObject* PyObject_GenericGetAttr(PyObject *o,
> PyObject *name)    Generic attribute getter function that is meant to
> be put into a type    object's tp_getattro slot.  It looks for a
> descriptor in the dictionary    of classes in the object's MRO as well
> as an attribute in the object's    :attr:~object.**dict** (if
> present).  As outlined in :ref:descriptors,    data descriptors take
> preference over instance attributes, while non-data    descriptors
> don't.  Otherwise, an :exc:AttributeError is raised.

Answer (score 6):

I find that no one mentions this difference:

`__getattribute__` has a default implementation, but `__getattr__` does not.

```py
class A:
    pass
a = A()
a.__getattr__ # error
a.__getattribute__ # return a method-wrapper
```

This has a clear meaning: since `__getattribute__` has a default implementation, while `__getattr__` not, clearly python encourages users to implement `__getattr__`.

Comment: Does python2 does not have default __getattribute__ ?

Comment: New style classes (which is the default in Python3) behave the same in both Python versions in this regard. (Python2 old style classes do not have a default `__getattribute__`.)

Answer (score 5):

In reading through Beazley & Jones PCB, I have stumbled on an explicit and practical use-case for `__getattr__` that helps answer the "when" part of the OP's question. From the book:

"The `__getattr__()` method is kind of like a catch-all for attribute lookup. It's a method that gets called if code tries to access an attribute that doesn't exist." We know this from the above answers, but in PCB recipe 8.15, this functionality is used to implement the **delegation design pattern**. If Object A has an attribute Object B that implements many methods that Object A wants to delegate to, rather than redefining all of Object B's methods in Object A just to call Object B's methods, define a `__getattr__()` method as follows:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self._b, name)
```

where _b is the name of Object A's attribute that is an Object B. When a method defined on Object B is called on Object A, the `__getattr__` method will be invoked at the end of the lookup chain. This would make code cleaner as well, since you do not have a list of methods defined just for delegating to another object.