# decorate or wrap the return value of a model field attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-middleware

Suppose I have a `Person` model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField()
    last_name = models.TextField()
```

I need a way to wrap `first_name` and `last_name` at a request-response layer (e.g through middleware).
For example, I may want to slightly modify the `first_name`. One way is doing it in every single place that needs it. Another way is to add a `get_first_name()` function that would do that for me, but this would require me to change thousands of occurrences of code directly accessing `first_name`. Another theoretical way, is to somehow wrap around or decorate the attribute through a middleware so that I can make modifications on the fly.

Perhaps something like this:

```
class ModifyFieldMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        Person._first_name = Person.first_name
        Person.first_name = modify_value(foo) #somehow pass the actual first_name here
```

Is there a way to do this in django without major hacking?

Comment: Can you use a `property`, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10383181/245915)?

Comment: so you want to modify the way you retrieve a variable??? you want person.first_name to NOT give you the actual value of first_name???

Comment: @Brian correct, with the complication that that variable is set by django internals when retrieving objects from the DB.

Comment: @nofinator Yes, something *like* that, but without changing the actual field name, since that would require major refactors everywhere in the codebase.

Comment: it's probably a horrible practice to straight change a default behaviour like that, after all retrieving a variable from a model is made to mimic normal class based object variables. i'd go for @nofinator 's comment, and use a property, even though this WILL require heavy refactoring, although it should jjust be a search and replace, but those operations always scare me on large codebases, so that's up to you xD