# Comparing PHP's __get() with __get__() and __getattr__() in Python

Tags: php, python

What is the difference between `__get__()` and `__getattr__()` in Python?  I come from a PHP background, where there is only `__get()`.  When should I use which function?

I've been trying to figure this out for a while.  I see plenty of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute-in-python), asking about the difference between `__getattr__()` and `__getattribute__()`, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find detailed documentation for all those methods  [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

Coming from PHP, you should first make yourself familiar with the Python object model. It's much richer than PHP, so you should not try to map your PHP knowledge 1:1 to Python. If you want to develop PHP, use PHP. If you want to develop in Python, learn Python.

Coming back to your original question: `__getattr__` is probably the function which does the same as the `__get` function in PHP. `__get__` in Python is used to implement descriptors. Details about descriptors can also be found in the documentation I mentioned above.

Comment: Also worth nothing that you should almost *never* have to access these methods directly. You might need to override them, but you should never call them.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Almost never, but a `classproperty(property)` that can't be shadowed by an instance might be handy, with `def __get__(self, obj, cls): return self.fget.__get__(cls, type(cls))()` and `def __set__(self, obj, val): self.fset.__get__(type(obj), type(type(obj)))(val)`.

Comment: Granted, `__getattr__()` is similar to PHP's `__get()`, but there are some important differences. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 10):

First an foremost, PHP does **not** have an equivalent to Python's `__get__()` – not even close! What you are looking for is most definitely `__getattr__()`.

> I come from a PHP background, where there is only `__get__`

**PHP** has a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) called [`__get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get), which is invoked whenever you are trying to access a property that does not exist.

### A short list of non-equivalents

First, let's clear some things up:

- PHP does **not** have an equivalent to Python's `__get__()`
- PHP does **not** have an equivalent to Python's `__getattr__()`
- PHP does **not** have an equivalent to Python's `__getattribute__()`
- Python does **not** have an equivalent to PHP's `__get()`

(And for all setter methods respectively.)

Contrary to Achim's assumption, `__get()` does **not** do the same as Python's `__getattr__()`!
Python does not distinguish between methods and properties, but PHP does, which is why PHP has a second method: `__call()`.

`__call()` is executed whenever you try to invoke a method on an object that does not exist. Python does not have an equivalent for this, because a method is simply an object (attribute) that is callable.

An example in PHP:

```php
<?php

$obj = new stdClass();
($obj->test)();
```

In Python, this would fail with an `AttributeError`. In PHP, however, this does *not even compile*:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' on line 4

Compare this to Python:

```py
obj.method()
# is eqvuivalent to:
(obj.method)()
```

This is an important difference. We conclude that the way PHP and Python think about calling methods are completely different.

### PHP's "call awareness"

- PHP's `obj` **knows** that you call a method

  - you get to handle calls to non-existing methods explicitly on the object you call on
  - this is because PHP's expression model is very inconsistent (PHP 5.4 is a small step forward though)
- but Python's `obj` does **not**.

This makes it possible for PHP to have `obj.does_not_exist` to evaluate to `3`, but `obj.does_not_exist()` to `5`.

To my knowledge, it's impossible to do so in Python. (This would allow us to describe PHP's inconsistency as a feature.)

Thus, we get to extend our "not equivalent"-list by one bullet point:

- Python does **not** have an equivalent to PHP's `__call()`/`__callStatic()`

### Summing it up

PHP provides two separate mechanisms:

- `__get()` for non-existing properties
- `__call()` for calls to non-existing methods

Python has only one mechanism, because it does not distinguish between properties and methods, as far as it is concerned they are all attributes.

- `__getattr__()` is invoked, when an attribute does not exist.
- `obj.non_existing()` is not special "call syntax", it's an expression to which the call operator `()` is applied: `(obj.__getattr__("non_existing"))()`

*Disclaimer*: `__getattr__()` is not always called when an attribute does not exist. `__getattribute__()` takes the highest precedence in the lookup chain and may thus cause `__getattr__()` to be ignored.

### Descriptors

`__get__()` in Python is something completely different from what has been addressed above.

The documentation describes descriptors to be `"a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”"`. I can sort of form an intuitive understanding what "binding behavior" is supposed to mean, but only because I already understand what descriptors do.

I would choose to describe descriptors  as "**self-aware** attributes" that can be shared across multiple classes.

Let me explain, what I mean by "self-awareness". Such attributes:

- **know** when they are being accessed or read from
- **know** when they are being written to
- **know** whom they are read/written via
- **know** when they are deleted

These attributes are independent objects: the "descriptor" objects, i.e. objects that adhere to the so called ["descriptor protocol"](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol), which defines a set of methods along with their corresponding signature that such objects can implement.

An object does not own a descriptor attribute. In fact, they belong to the object's corresponding class (or an ancestor thereof). However, the same descriptor object can "belong" to multiple classes.

*Note*: "whom they are read via", what is the proper way to refer to `obj` in `obj.attr`? I would say: `attr` is accessed "via" `obj`.