# Python property callable

Tags: python, properties, callable

Is there any way to have a property and a method with the same name?
I mean a property that can be used the usual way **and** to be callable at the same time? 
Like this:

```
>>> b = Book()
>>> b.pages
123
>>> b.pages()
123
>>> b.pages(including_toc=False)
123
>>> b.pages(including_toc=True)
127
```

Comment: In case you are coming from PHP where this is directly supported by the language, see [here for some similar differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11901500/383124) where I also mention the attributes vs methods distinction that PHP makes but Python doesn't. P.S. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't.

`()` always calls an *object* from the expression on its left-hand side.

What this means is, that `b.pages()` can be read as follows:

```
_tmp = b.pages
_tmp()
```

As you can see, methods *are* attributes.

What you *could* (but shouldn't) do is wrap integers in some custom class and provide a `__call__` method… but I would advise against such black magic.

Comment: Yes, the first thing that came to mind for me was subclassing `int`.

Comment: @eryksun In your case, I would probably just go with a function and accept that you always have to call it, or a second attribute called `.pages_including_toc`

Comment: Oh crap, I thought so. In this particular case, I'll go the @phant0m way.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was subclass `int` and add a `__call__` method (plus instance data as required, such `toc_num_pages`). I was agreeing that this is over the top.

Comment: @eryksun No worries, I undestood what you meant ;)

Comment: this is why people should not use python properties.

Answer (score 5):

A instance of your `Book` class can only have one attribute called `pages`. That attribute can be anything (an integer, a callable function, anything really), but it can only be *one* thing.

Another way of viewing things is at the byte-code level - given two lines of code:

```
>>> def a():
...     book.pages
...     book.pages()
...
```

Here is what it [`disassembles`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html):

```
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (book)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (pages)
              6 POP_TOP

  3           7 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (book)
             10 LOAD_ATTR                1 (pages)
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            0
  [...a few more irrelevant lines...]
```

The first line (`book.pages`) loads the `book` object, and from that loads the `pages` attribute (`LOAD_ATTR`)

The second line (`book.pages()`) does the exact same thing, loads the `book` object, loads the `pages` attribute, *then* calls the `CALL_FUNCTION` attribute.

There is no sane way you can make the `LOAD_ATTR` return something different based on how it will eventually be used. The closest you can get is to return a weird object which acts like both

```
>>> class WeirdInteger(int):
...   def __call__(self, including_toc):
...     print "WeirdInteger(%s) called" % (self)
...
>>> a = WeirdInteger(10)
>>> a
10
>>> a*2
20
>>> a()
WeirdInteger(10) called
```

..but, don't do that. No one using you code will expect the `pages` attribute to work like this, and bits of code the `pages` will be passed to might require an actual integer.

Instead design your `Books` class differently (maybe make `pages` an regular function, or add a separate property for the `pages_without_toc`)

Answer (score 3):

> **Short Answer**: No, as properties and methods are attributes of a class and are part of the same namespace.
>   So, which one gets declared later overrides the previous one.

Comment: I would advise against the wording `share the same namespace`, since methods effectively *are* attributes, that happen to be callable.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your main goal is to have `pages` return a different value if a particular flag is set. One approach that might work, depending on your goal, would be to make `pages` a property (in the precise Python sense) rather than an attribute. Then have it return a value with `toc` or without, depending on whether a flag is set. So for example:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, toc, pages):
        self._toc = toc
        self._pages = pages
        self.include_toc = False

    @property
    def pages(self):
        if self.include_toc:
            return self._pages + self._toc
        else:
            return self._pages
```

Here's how it would work:

```
>>> b = Book(5, 55)
>>> b.pages
55
>>> b.include_toc = True
>>> b.pages
60
```

This doesn't do *exactly* what you've asked for, but it is as good or better for a certain subset of use cases (i.e. those in which you will be making multiple calls to `pages` with the flag set, only changing the flag occasionally -- such as when `include_toc` is set by an end user, or when a particular book should almost always or almost never include the `_toc` in its page count.)

However, as phant0m points out, the flag is persistent, so this could generate unexpected results in some cases, if you set it and then fail to reset it when you're done. And as eryksun points out, a context manager is a classic solution to that problem.

While this may indeed be overengineering, it's so simple that I'll demonstrate it nonetheless. Simply add this to the definition of `Book`:

```
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def set_toc_reset(self, state):
        try:
            old_flag = self.include_toc
            self.include_toc = state
            yield self
        finally:
            self.include_toc = old_flag
```

This takes care of resetting the flag for you:

```
>>> from foo import Book
>>> b = Book(5, 55)
>>> with b.set_toc_reset(True):
...     print b.pages
... 
60
>>> b.include_toc
False
```

Comment: Note that the converse is true as well, remember not to forget setting `include_toc` before accessing the `pages`, or you can get unexpected results. For instance, you might have added some code further above that needed a different setting, but forgot to revert its status.

Comment: You could make this a context manager, such as `with b.include_toc(): pages = b.pages`. The method `include_toc` could set `self._include_toc = True`, and `__exit__` could reset it. But this is over-engineering this problem compared to simply having a separate property.

Comment: @eryksun, you're right that it probably is over-engineering in many cases. But still worth considering, I think, given how easy it is to create a context manager.