# Change representation of Python object

Tags: python, object

In Python, data types (like int, float) both represent a value, but also have some built-in attributes/functions/etc:

```
In [1]: a = 1.2

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 1.2

In [3]: a.is_integer()
Out[3]: False
```

Is it possible to reproduce this behavior within Python, e.g. define a class:

```
class Scalar:
    def __init__(self, value)
        self.value = value

    # other code ....

s = Scalar(1.2)
```

where I could have `s` return 1.2 (instead of typing `s.value`), and do things like `a = s` -> `a = 1.2`? The closest I can get to this behavior is adding something like:

```
def __getitem__(self, key=None):
    return self.value
```

and using `a = s[()]`, but that doesn't look very good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python property callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029254/python-property-callable)

Comment: In particular, see the snippet with a `WeirdInteger` class.

Comment: This isn't a general solution, but you could make your `Scalar` class in your example work the way you want by simply subclassing float (or int, or whatever other scalar type you wanted to mimic). `class Scalar(float): pass; s = Scalar(1.2)`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024646/is-it-possible-to-overload-python-assignment

Comment: subclassing a type might work, I have to see if it works for my (more complicated..) problem, but I'll give it a try!

Comment: @julbra Did you get something working? I was interested to see what answer you accepted and you haven't accepted one yet.

Comment: @ Two-Bit Alchemist I didn't except an answer because none of them produced the behavior I was looking for. Subclassing e.g. float works partly, but it doesn't allow me to add other arguments (from your example, e.g. `s=Scalar(1.2, 'bla'`), and adding `__call__` comes close, but having to write e.g. `s()` to retrieve `value` isn't very nice. And accepting an answer that didn't answer my question seems wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where I could have s return 1.2 (instead of typing s.value)

In the console? Then implement the `__repr__` method.

> a = s -> a = 1.2

To avoid having to use `a = s.value`, you can implement `__call__` and call the object:

```
>>> class Scalar:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return str(self.value)
...     def __call__(self):
...         return self.value
... 
>>> s = Scalar(1.2)
>>> s
1.2
>>> a = s()
>>> a
1.2
```

Check the documentation about the [data model on emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

For example:

```
class Scalar:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __call__(self):
        return self.value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Scalar(self.value + other.value)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value
    def ___le__(self, other):
        return self.value <= other.value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.value != other.value
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other.value
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.value >= other.value
```

Can be used like this:

```
>>> s1 = Scalar(1.2)
>>> s2 = Scalar(2.1)
>>> s1 + s2
3.3
>>> s1 < s2
True
>>> s1 > s2
False
>>> s1 != s2
True
>>> s1 <= s2
True
>>> s1 >= s2
False
```

There are also the [`__int__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) and [`__float__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__float__) magic methods, which you can implement and use like this (this is more semantically correct):

```
>>> a = int(s)
>>> a = float(s)
```

Comment: Well, the `__call__` gets rid of one set of brackets, so that's an improvement ;-) If I can't find another solution and the suggestions from above (using `class Scalar(float)`) don't work, it might be an acceptable solution

Comment: `__repr__` is going to complain if you try to return anything but a string: `TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type float)`. This also won't affect assignment statements (`a = s`) as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that's not possible for your `a = s` example. You would have to change the behavior of `=`, the assignment operator. The assignment operator doesn't really do anything to the object on the right, it just copies a reference to it (in the case of an object, at least).

In general, it is possible to change the behavior of built in operators for your custom classes using [operator overloading](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python), but Python doesn't provide this sort of option for assignment (`=`) because of how different it is from operators like addition (`+`) and even equality (`==`).

Comment: Why is this answer getting downvoted when it says essentially the exact same thing as all of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024646/is-it-possible-to-overload-python-assignment)?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - It says "that's not possible" when basic subclassing makes it possible.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Kind of... It doesn't make it possible in the general case, and it doesn't make sense to subclass, say, string if this is the _only_ behavior you want.

Comment: This answer is correct. It only answers part of the question but since `=` can't be overridden OP can't get the complete behaviour they were after.