# Nested objects and setattr & getattr (yes, it's that time)

Tags: python

Overview:

```
class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Outer(object):
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.inner = Inner(z)

o = Outer(10)
```

Now, I want the Outer object to behave transparently -- any attributes set on `o` should be set on `o.inner`, same for reading: `o.something` should return, in fact, the value of `o.inner.sommething`. Kind of like a proxy or a relay.

`__getattr__` for `Outer` seems simple & works:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    return getattr(self, item)
```

How would I handle `__setattr__`? I couldn't come up with anything that didn't cause a recursion error and make me hate myself.

Or is the concept itself flawed?

(Another approach I tried was making `Outer` a subclass of `Inner` -- this didn't really play aesthetically the present`@classmethods`, not to mention the IDE would get lost inside those - not able to resolve some attributes. Let's leave that for now, perhaps?)

Comment: Did you mean `self.inner = Inner(z)`?  Also, does your getattr method return data from Inner()?  The way it is written, it looks like it would just reference Outer.

Comment: Yes - it does return. Fixed both, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tricky part is setting the `inner` attribute of the `Outer` class correctly. What you can do is call the `__setattribute__` method of `object` (base class of `Outer`):

```
class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Outer(object):    
    def __init__(self, z):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'inner', Inner(z))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.inner, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        return setattr(self.inner, name, value)
```

Now, it works correctly:

```
o = Outer(10)
print o.x        # 10
print o.inner.x  # 10
o.g = 3
print o.g        # 3
print o.inner.g  # 3
```

However, it's not clear to my why you don't want to use inheritance in this case. It seems more natural and pythonic to have `Outer` inherit from `Inner`.

Comment: And the reason print(o.inner) works is because o.inner already exists so it doesn't call `__getattr__` and try to return o.inner.inner, correct?  It's not obvious that `__getattr__` does not get called in cases where the requested item already exists as part of the object in question.

Comment: @gfortune, yes; for more see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute-in-python).

Comment: yes, see [\_\_getattr\_\_](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) docs