# How to load a pyYAML file and access it using attributes instead of using the dictionary notation?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have an YAML config that looks like:

```
config:
 - id: foo
 - name: bar
content:
 - run: xxx
 - remove: yyy
```

I am using Python YAML module to load it but I want to access it in better ways like:

```
stream = open(filename)
config = load(stream, Loader=Loader)
print(config['content'])
```

What I want is to be able to do: `print(config.content)`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Comment: @Justin: This isn't a duplicate of this question, because you can simply patch the YAML loader to create objects of whatever class you desire rather than instances of `dict`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use object notation with dictionaries using the following class, as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761899/623518) answer:

```
class DictAsMember(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        value = self[name]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = DictAsMember(value)
        return value
```

This class in action:

```
>>> my_dict = DictAsMember(one=1, two=2)
>>> my_dict
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
>>> my_dict.two
2
```

**Edit** This works recursively with sub-dictionaries, for example:

```
>>> my_dict = DictAsMember(one=1, two=2, subdict=dict(three=3, four=4))
>>> my_dict.one
1
>>> my_dict.subdict
{'four': 4, 'three': 3}
>>> my_dict.subdict.four
4
```

Comment: I think that this does not work recursively, as you can imagine the same problem repeats for other entries in the config tree.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, this does work recursively. Does my edit answer your point?

Comment: Why is this (the simplest answer out there) not upvoted a million times? There are dozens of similar/duplicate questions that answer this in such a complicated way!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is probably to overwrite the YAML constructor for `tag:yaml.org,2002:map` so it returns a custom dictionary class instead of an ordinary dictionary.

```
import yaml

class AttrDict(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self._attr = attr
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self._attr[attr]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError

def construct_map(self, node):
    # WARNING: This is copy/pasted without understanding!
    d = {}
    yield AttrDict(d)
    d.update(self.construct_mapping(node))

# WARNING: We are monkey patching PyYAML, and this will affect other clients!    
yaml.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', construct_map)

YAML = """
config:
  - id: foo
  - name: bar
content:
  - run: xxx
  - remove: yyy
"""

obj = yaml.load(YAML)

print(obj.config[0].id) # prints foo
```

Note that this will break everything else in the process that uses YAML, if it expects everything to work the normal Python way.  You can use a custom loader, but I personally find the PyYAML documentation a bit labyrinthine, and it seems that side effects are global and contagious as a rule rather than an exception.

You have been warned.

**As an alternative,** if your schema is relatively static you could write your own classes and deserialize to those (e.g., `class Config` with `id` and `name` properties).  It probably wouldn't be worth the cost of the extra code, however.

Comment: Simplified and improved this into https://gist.github.com/ktaragorn/9cf6d368378b0f65a3a0. There is no monkeypatching and it works in a nested fashion as well

Comment: @KarthikT: Fails for dictionaries nested inside arrays.

Comment: I hadnt even considered that use case.. does that happen often when you are considering config files?

Comment: Yes, I think it would happen often.  For example, when configuring a web server, you'd have a list of different virtual hosts.