# pyyaml and yaml sublevels

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I´m trying to use PyYAML to parse a YAML file into a python object

However I doubt raised during the course

I have the YAML file

```
first_lvl:
   second_lvl:
       item_a:
          - value_a : "value aaa"
          - value_b : "value bbb"
```

My python script reads and loads the YAML into an object

```
import yaml

class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

with open(job_file.yml) as f:
    skeleton = yaml.full_load(f)

MyJob = Struct(**skeleton)

print(MyJob.first_lvl)
```

And that that works fine but only for the first level of the YAML. How about if I want to reach the sub-level values of yaml file that suppose to be contained into the object

like this :

```
    print(MyJob.first_lvl.second_lvl)
```

It might not be related with a PyYAML module thing and more the way python handles objects, but I´m still lost

Can anyone shed some lights?

Comment: Unless you import a module `job_file` in which is declared a string `yml` that is the filename of the file you want to open, your code is not actually what you are using. And if you meant to writeh `with open('job_file.yml')` please note that the [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you expect to get is five `Struct` instances, one for each of the mappings in your YAML file (each of which happen to havieonly one key-value pair)? You should just make a different `Loader` that creates the `Struct` directly instead of first making dicts. Do you need to use PyYAML, i.e. are you sure you will only need to support the 10+ year old YAML 1.1 standard that PyYAML partially supports?

Comment: @Anthon fixed the filename to yaml

Comment: @Anthon i think its fine to have just one instance, i´m just in doubt how would be the best way to interact with objected that was created
Initially I was trying use pyyaml, is there a better option to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you indicate you would prefer to have only one
`Struct` instance loaded. However if you want to access the value
`"value aaa"` by writing
`my_job.first_lvl.second_lvl.item_a.0.value_a`, you **cannot** do so
by providing the `__getattr__` method, as this will throw an error
stating that the `dict` object has not attribute `second_lvl` (it only
has a key `second_lvl`). The `__getattr__` never gets called because,
on the `Struct` instance, attribute lookup doesn't fail.

What you can do is provide some method `lookup` that as argument takes a "dotted" string:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
first_lvl:
   second_lvl:
       item_a:
          - value_a : "value aaa"
          - value_b : "value bbb"
"""

class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

    def lookup(self, s):
        def recurse(d, names):
            name = names[0]
            if isinstance(d, list):  # list indices cannot be strings
                name = int(name)                
            if len(names) > 1:
                return recurse(d[name], names[1:])
            return d[name]

        names = s.split('.')
        return recurse(getattr(self, names[0]), names[1:])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
my_job = Struct(**yaml.load(yaml_str))

print(my_job.lookup("first_lvl.second_lvl.item_a.0.value_a"))
```

which gives:

```
value aaa
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485868/1307905) shows an alternative extending
the default data-structure when using ruamel.yaml in round-trip-mode.

If you really want to write
`my_job.first_lvl.second_lvl.item_a.0.value_a`, without quotes, I
don't think there is a way around making every level aware of looking
up attributes. That means extending `Struct`, so
that the class can be constructed from mapping **and** sequences. That can be done
after loading the YAML, but IMO is best done during the construction of the YAML.