# Automatic redis lookup for python objects

Tags: python, object, redis, getattribute

I'm trying to implement classes for which redis actually holds the attributes, but the user of the class is not aware of this (ie. object persistence across multiple clients).  I know there are a few libs that wrap redis for python but none do exactly this in this simple way (but please correct me if I'm wrong on this!)

I've successfully implemented automatic redis storage of attributes but I can't seem to get retrieval to work using `__getattribute__` without infinite recursion blowing it up.  I think I am being careful about using `object.__getattribute__` etc. but obviously I must be missing something:

```
class redisStored(object):
    global redis

    # A class method to implement object retrieval from redis
    # Call <Classname>.load(<id>) to create a new instance which exists in redis
    @classmethod
    def load(cls,id):
        # Create the object
        obj = cls.__new__(cls)
        # Set id without calling obj's __setattr__
        object.__setattr__(obj,'id',int(id))
        # Return the object we created
        return obj

    def __str__(self):
        # Return "<ClassName>:<id>" to differentiate ids in redis
        # You can use this to say redis.hgetall(g) where g is the instance

        return "%s:%s" % (self.__class__.__name__, str(object.__getattribute__(self,'id')))
        #                                     self.id here ^ would cause infinite recursion

    # This works fine
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        redis.hset(self,name,value)
        return object.__setattr__(self,name,value)

    # This blows up with infinite recursion, WHY??
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        _val = redis.hget(self,name)
        if not _val:
            return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        else:
            return _val
```

If I trace this it blows up inside `_val = redis.hget(self,name)` but I can't figure out why.   Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without more detail on "it blows up", I am afraid we can't really help with why it does it.

Comment: Sorry - to be more specific, it blows up due to infinite recursion inside redis.hget(self,name). So somewhere inside hget it is calling getattr on the same object and that's what I can't figure out. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding what's going on with getattr ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be very carefull with `__getattribute__` overloading.

A side effect is that accessing `self.__class__` calls `__getattribute__` and creates a dummy redis query.

As you are using new-style classes you may want to use `__getattr__` instead and avoid infinite recursion problem, although if you use `__getattr__` you will return object attribute **prior** to redis value if this attribute already exists in your instance.

Anyway your object is kind-of immutable as long as you overloaded `__setattribute__` method so this is not a big issue.

Please refer to this SO response for a more detailed difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` : [Difference between __getattr__ vs __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  `_getattr__` doesn't solve my problem because I need the attribute to come from redis (in case something else has updated it).  I've decided a better approach is to have a `get('<fieldname>')` method - that way it's obvious that we are _getting_ a value (from redis) rather than hiding it behind apparent normal class functionality.