# Why "__getattr__" does not work in python "ctypes"?

Tags: python, ctypes, getattr

I stop it in the example of "datetime", is rewritten in a real example of lxml.
(It may be strange because English is translated in Google Translate is my statement I'm sorry.)

It is thought that I like lxml from very good performance, but the source is hard to read.
If you are actively using the XML, I do frequently can also be modified code of python.
Time has passed since forgotten, source because very difficult to understand,
I have taken the time to debug and fix.
For example, I think usually when you search as follows: deep XML hierarchy.

```
elem = lxml.etree.parse ("xxx/xxx/sample.xml").getroot()

elem.xpath("//depth3/text()")[0]

elem.find("./depth1/depth2/depth3").get("attr1").text
```

I wanted to use as follows.
(Use this code it's just me.)

```
elem.depth3.text (Ex.1)
OR
elem.depth1.depth2.depth3.text (Ex.2)
```

I tried the class inheritance is first to implement this.
You have customized a little bit by referring to the "Using custom Element classes in lxml".
I used the `__getattr__` in order to search an XML element.

```
from lxml import etree
class CustomElement (etree.ElementBase):
    def __ getattr__ (self, k):
        ret = self.xpath ("/ /" + k)
        setattr(self, k, ret)
        return getattr(self, k)
```

Example of (Ex.1) to succeed.
**But the example of (Ex.2) becomes Attribute Error `__getattr__` is not present in the instance of the return of etree._Element depth1.**

Although not (supplemental) practical, but I used an example of adding a "millisecond" of "datetime" in the first question from Easy to understand.

It was thought then it was a way to add functions to the Element class of lxml using the ctypes module.

```
import ctypes
import lxml.etree

class PyObject_HEAD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('HEAD', ctypes.c_ubyte * (object.__basicsize__ -
                           ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p))),
        ('ob_type', ctypes.c_void_p)
    ]
def __getattr__(self, k):
    ret = self.xpath("//" + k)
    setattr(self, k, ret)
    return getattr(self, k)

_get_dict          = ctypes.pythonapi._PyObject_GetDictPtr
_get_dict.restype  = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)
_get_dict.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]

EE = _get_dict(lxml.etree._Element).contents.value
EE["__getattr__"] = __getattr__

elem = lxml.etree.parse("xxx/xxx/sample.xml").getroot()
elem.xpath("//depth3")[0]
```

=> Return _Element object

```
from ispect import getsource
print getsource(elem.__getattr__)
```

=>def `__getattr__`(self, k):
=>    ret = self.xpath("//" + k)
=>    setattr(self, k, ret)
=>    return getattr(self, k)
**sources is added..**

```
elem.depth3
```

=> AttributeError .. no attribute 'depth3'

**I do not know if or should I write how using the "PyObject_GetAttr".

Please tell me if.**
Best regards
====================Previous Question===================================
I'm trying to enhancements in ctypes.
Add function usually go well.
However, it does not work if you add a special method and Why?

```
import ctypes as c

class PyObject_HEAD(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('HEAD', c.c_ubyte * (object.__basicsize__ -
                              c.sizeof(c.c_void_p))),
        ('ob_type', c.c_void_p)
    ]

pgd = c.pythonapi._PyObject_GetDictPtr
pgd.restype = c.POINTER(c.py_object)
pgd.argtypes = [c.py_object]

import datetime

def millisecond(td):
    return (td.microsecond / 1000)

d = pgd(datetime.datetime)[0]
d["millisecond"] = millisecond

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.millisecond(), now.microsecond
```

This prints `155 155958`, Ok!

```
def __getattr__(self, k):
    return self, k

d["__getattr__"] = __getattr__

now = datetime.datetime
print now.hoge
```

This doesn't work, why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxtmp.py", line 31, in <module>
    print now.hoge
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'hoge'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PyObject_GetAttr`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/object.c#l1170) (Objects/object.c) uses the type's `tp_getattro` slot, or `tp_getattr` if the former isn't defined. It doesn't look up `__getattribute__` in the MRO of the type.

For a custom `__getattr__` you'll need to subclass `datetime`. Your heap type will use [`slot_tp_getattr_hook`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/typeobject.c#l5471) (Objects/typeobject.c) as its `tp_getattro`. This function will look for `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` in the type's MRO by calling [`_PyType_Lookup`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/typeobject.c#l2478) (Objects/typeobject.c).

---

Given your update, see ["using custom Element classes in lxml"](http://lxml.de/1.3/element_classes.html). For multiple results I've hacked a `__getattr__` hook that uses a suffix notation for the index. It defaults to index 0 otherwise. Admittedly I haven't given it much thought, but clashes with existing names can be avoided if you always use the index.

```
from lxml import etree

def make_parser(element):
    lookup = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup(element=element)
    parser = etree.XMLParser()
    parser.setElementClassLookup(lookup)
    return parser

class CustomElement(etree.ElementBase):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            name, index = attr.rsplit('_', 1)
            index = int(index)
        except ValueError:
            name = attr
            index = 0
        return self.xpath(name)[index]

parser = make_parser(CustomElement)
```

For example:

```
>>> spam = etree.fromstring(r'''
... <spam>
...     <foo>
...         <bar>eggs00</bar>
...         <bar>eggs01</bar>
...     </foo>
...     <foo>
...         <bar>eggs10</bar>
...         <bar>eggs11</bar>
...     </foo>
... </spam>
... ''', parser)

>>> spam.foo_0.bar_0.text
'eggs00'
>>> spam.foo_0.bar_1.text
'eggs01'
>>> spam.foo_1.bar_0.text
'eggs10'
>>> spam.foo_1.bar_1.text
'eggs11'
```

Comment: Thank you for answers. Is it will be any source specifically If you modify my example? Please tell me for beginners. I'm sorry

Comment: Thank you for advice.<br>
Although I read just a little "Using custom Element classes in lxml",<br>
I might just do not understand.<br>
I will try reading again one more time. It takes time because it is not good at English.<br>

Comment: **_thank you!!!!!!!!!!!very cool code!!_**  I didn't Understand mean of "Using custom Element classes in lxml" thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override `__getattr__` that way. Basically, you are hacking the object's `__dict__` to include a new method. If you call `now.millisecond`, the original "attribute getter" gets called, looks into the dict, and returns you're new method. I'm not sure where this attribute getter resides (might be in C code), but it can't be in the dict it looks up stuff in - so you can't override it this way.

You *might* try `__getattribute__` instead, but I don't know whether that will work either. Be aware that it's much harder to implement correctly (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278104/143091).

That being said, it's probably not a good idea to hack builtins this way. A lot of python standard library code might depend on behavior that you change, and your code might fail in hard to understand ways. Also it's confusing for people who know python and try to understand you're code.

I hope you don't have this nasty trick from me. I *only* use it to backport features that are not available in older versions of python, or a library, for example:

```
if not hasattr(wnck.Screen, "get_workspaces"):
    def get_workspaces(screen):
        return [screen.get_workspace(i) for i in range(screen.get_workspace_count())]
        _get_dict(wnck.Screen)[0]['get_workspaces'] = get_workspaces
```

This way, I can develop primarily for the modern version of the library, but still support ancient versions if just a function or two are missing, without having to change my code.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I used the datetime for good example. I would like to really I want to extend the c modules of lxml. I want to upload to make an example later