# What is the use of lambda in this python code?

Tags: python, lambda

Here is a code extracted and adapted from Learning Python, what is the use of `lambda` in line 5 `return lambda *args: '[Getattr str]'`, it seems `print(X.__str__())` expect 0 arguments, is `*args` unnecessary here?

```
class GetAttr:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print('getattr: ' + attr)
        if attr == '__str__':
            return lambda *args: '[Getattr str]'
        else:
            return lambda *args: None

X = GetAttr()
print(X.__call__('why', 'any', 'number', 'of', 'arguments', 'here')) 
print(X.__str__())   # but not here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `attr == '__str__'`, the function needs to return a callable object, because `__str__` is expected to be a method. Simply returning a string will give you an error complaining that 'str' objects aren't callable.

However, the `*args` is not needed because `__str__` is never called with any arguments. This suffices:

```
return lambda: '[Getattr str]'
```

Note that if you use python2 and inherit from `object` as is recommended, the example doesn't work. And if you use python3, it doesn't work either. This is the output in those cases:

```
getattr: __call__
None
<__main__.GetAttr object at 0xb728ff6c>
```

Why isn't `__getattr__` invoked when `attr == '__str__'`?

It's because the base class `object` already implements a default `__str__` method, and our `__getattr__` function is only called for *missing* attributes. To fix the example as it is we must use the `__getattribute__` method instead, but [beware of the dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278104/566644).

```
class GetAttr(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        print('getattr: ' + attr)
        if attr == '__str__':
            return lambda: '[Getattr str]'
        else:
            return lambda *args: None
```

A better and more readable solution would be to simply override the `__str__` method explicitly.

```
class GetAttr(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print('getattr: ' + attr)
        return lambda *args: None

    def __str__(self):
        return '[Getattr str]'
```

But though it's better python, much of the point of the example is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Its for crushing any args handed to it. No matter how many args you put into `__str__()` it will always ignore them basically.

On the other hand this is horribly terribly written Python. You might wanna try something else instead

Answer (score 0):

The `lambda` makes the function return a function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is unnecessary in this case, since `X.__str__()` will always be called without arguments. It depends what behaviour you want when it is incorrectly called with args:

```
str1 = lambda *args: "[Getattr str]"
str2 = lambda : "[Getattr str]"

str1(1,2,3) #works, args ignored
str2(1,2,3) #throws runtime error
```