# Is there a way to ensure validation is performed on a variable than @property?

Tags: python, validation, properties

I'm writing a library that parses a file, creates an object that represents the file, and allows exporting the object back to a file.

I want to validate that the required headers and columns are included any time those values are changed. Due to this, I was trying to setup validation with the @property decorator.

I noticed in the python documentation for @property they use '_variable' if the property name was 'variable'. I understand that a single underscore in front is to signify the variable is intended for weak internal use. However, I was under the impression the point of the @property decorator was that any call to set a variable would cause the setter function to run.

```
_headers = None

required_headers = ['FIELD_DELIM', 'VIDEO_FORMAT', 'FPS']

@property
def headers(self):
    return self._headers

@headers.setter
def headers(self, value):
    for header in self.required_headers:
        if header not in value:
            raise Exception
    self._headers = value
```

While this code works, I know that I can still bypass my setter by doing myObject._headers=value.

Is there a way I can ensure that validation is always performed without relying on a user to respect _headers is for internal use?

Comment: As a side note, `_headers = None` is setting a _class_ attribute, one shared by all instances of the class, not an _instance_ attribute. A `@property`, on the other hand, is for per-instance values. So, your code as written is misleading at best.

Comment: I took out the _headers = None from my class, it really wasn't needed. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is not designed to help you "ensure" that nobody misuses your objects like that. The underscore prefix for private attributes, and the `@property` mechanism for hiding attributes behind getters and setters, can ensure that it's obvious that people *shouldn't* use your objects like that, and make it harder for them to do so *accidentally*, but it can't prevent them from actually doing so maliciously.

While there are tricks you can use to hide your attributes even better, in a highly dynamic, introspectable language like Python, there's always going to be a way to get around that—look directly in your `__dict__`, or in whatever other attribute you hide them in, or just change the `__class__` of your object to something less restrictive.

In other words, you already *can* rely on a user to respect that `_headers` is for internal use if all you're worried about is your users being idiots; if you're worried about them being malicious, Python is the wrong language for you.

Comment: I was mainly concerned with people looking at my source, not understanding what @property is, and then using the _headers version instead. Thanks.

Comment: @KEngle That's what doc strings are for.  :)

Comment: @KEngle: If you're writing code to be used by novices, and expecting them to use the code as its own docs, you may well want to add some extra comments, like `self._headers = None # don't set this directly in your code, use the spam.header property` or similar, as well as a doc string listing the public attributes (whether real or `@property`).

Comment: @SilasRay: Thanks for getting there before me, and more concisely. :)

Comment: @KEngle: Also, note that many introspection features will leave out underscore-prefixed attributes by default, which helps. For example, if I fire up IPython, `import` your class, create an instance, and write `instance.` and then use tab completion, it will show me `headers` but not `_headers`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use double underscore for name mangling or implement a custom descriptor, but one of Python's core tenets is that users are expected to be "consenting adults" who respect interfaces and do their best not to do things that break interfaces without a very good reason.  Basically, don't worry about it and just use the single underscore to store the data on the object.

Answer (score 1):

No, Python doesn't enforce the concept of **private** vs **public** like Java does

Comment: Python does have the concept of private vs. public; that's what the underscore prefix is. It just doesn't try to _enforce_ that concept the way that, say, Java does.

Comment: Also, your simplified version doesn't simplify things, it changes the logic completely. He's asking if any of his `required_headers` is a _substring_ of `value`, you're asking if any of them _equal_ `value`.

Comment: I know, but one can always access the obj.__dict__ or whatever underscored variable / member

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what "doesn't try to enforce that concept the way that, say, Java does" means. It still _has_ the concept.

Answer (score 1):

sort of. there's no real privacy in python and with a little work a user can circumvent your privacy safegauards.

if you want, you could implement `__getattribute__` which checks any time you try to access an element of your class, but even that's not foolproof. check out this link [Difference between __getattr__ vs __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute-in-python)