# What is the python attribute get and set order?

Tags: python, class, attributes, metaprogramming, instance-variables

Python provides us many possibilities on instance/class attribute, for example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "hello"

a = A()
```

There are many ways to access/change the value of `self.foo`:

1. direct access `a.foo`
2. inner dict `a.__dict__['foo']`
3. get and set `a.__get__` and `a.__set__`,of course there two are pre-defined methods.
4. getattribute `a.__getattribute__`
5. `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`
6. maybe more.

While reading source code, I always get lost of what's their ultimate access order? When I use `a.foo`, how do I know which method/attribute will get called actually?

Comment: 1. `foo` is an *instance attribute*, not a class attribute. 2. As it isn't a `@property` (or other descriptor) `__get__` and `__set__` won't be involved.

Comment: For e.g. `__getattr__` vs. `__getattribute__`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3278077/3001761

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar = a.foo`...

1. invokes `a.__getattribute__('foo')`
2. which in turn by default looks up `a.__dict__['foo']`
3. or invokes `foo`'s `.__get__()` if defined on `A`.

The returned value would then be assigned to `bar`.

---

`a.foo = bar`...

1. invokes `a.__getattribute__('foo')`
2. which in turn by default looks up `a.__dict__['foo']`
3. or invokes `foo`'s `.__set__(bar)` if defined on A.

Comment: Well explained. great.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate; `__get__` and `__set__` are for descriptors, which are stored on the *class*, so wouldn't be found in `a.__dict__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe tweaked to be more technically correct.

Comment: I also think this is still not completely correct. First `_getattribute__` will check if it is a descriptor by looking for `__get__()` in the class definition `A.foo` (when `a = A()`). If it is found then it is used, if not the next step is to look in the instance dict `a.__dict__['foo']`

Answer (score 18):

I found out [this great post](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup) that has a detailed explanation on object/class attribute lookup.

**For object attribute lookup:**

Assuming `Class` is the class and `instance` is an instance of `Class`, evaluating `instance.foobar` roughly equates to this:

- Call the type slot for `Class.__getattribute__` (`tp_getattro`). The default does this:

  - Does `Class.__dict__` have a `foobar` item that is a data descriptor ?

    - If yes, return the result of `Class.__dict__['foobar'].__get__(instance, Class)`.
  - Does `instance.__dict__` have a `'foobar'` item in it?

    - If yes, return `instance.__dict__['foobar']`.
  - Does `Class.__dict__` have a `foobar` item that is not a data descriptor [9]?

    - If yes, return the result of `Class.__dict__['foobar'].__get__(instance, klass)`. [6]
- If the attribute still wasn't found, and there's a `Class.__getattr__`, call `Class.__getattr__('foobar')`.

There is an illustrated image for this:

[image]

Please do check out the original blog if interested which gives a outstanding explanation on python class, attribute lookup, and metaclass.

Comment: how confusing - one route checks class dict then instance dict then class dict again ?!!

Comment: This chart is just what I needed. I'm curious tho how `__slots__` members fit in there. I'm guessing in the same spot as instance dict, but using `__slots__`, instance dict doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @JasonForbes Slots are actually just data descriptors. Try `class Demo: __slots__ = ['foo']`, and then look at the value of `Demo.foo`. It's an object with a `__get__` and a `__set__` method.

Comment: There are a few inaccuracies in this answer: 1) "Does `Class.__dict__` have a foobar item" is incorrect because python actually looks for `foobar` in the `__dict__`s of all classes in the [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) of `Class`. Or to put it differently: `foobar` can also come from a parent class. 2) If `foobar` is a class attribute but not a descriptor, python won't call `__get__` on it. (Obviously, that wouldn't work because the method doesn't exist.)