# Subclassing in python of instantiated superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

Is it possible to subclass in Python using an already instantiated superclass?

I don't exactly know how to frame the question so let me give an example. Suppose I have a class Rectangle and I want to build another class ColoredRectangle. But I don't want each `ColoredRectangle` of the same dimensions to be its own new `Rectangle`. So when I initiate `ColoredRectangle` I would pass it an already instantiated `Rectangle`.

Ie., I want

```
r = Rectangle([1,2])
r_red = ColoredRectangle(r, "red")
r_blue = ColoredRectangle(r, "blue")
```

But now `r_red` and `r_blue` should be able to get all rectangle methods and attributes. For example suppose `Rectangle` had an `area()` attribute.

```
r.area
2
r_red.area
2
```

`r_red` and `r_blue` should "point" to the same `Rectangle`. I know I could do this by writing:

```
 class ColoredRectangle(Rectangle):

      def __init__(self, rectangle, color):
          self.color = color
          self.rectangle = rectangle
```

But then I'd have to write

```
  r_red.rectangle.area
```

which is ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Inheritance

Inheritance is such a nice thing in python, and I don't think you have to resort to `getattr` hacks, if you want those, scroll down.

You can **force** the class dictionary to refer to another object:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height


class ColoredRectangle(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, rect, color):
        self.__dict__ = rect.__dict__
        self.color = color


rect = Rectangle(3, 5)
crect = ColoredRectangle(rect, color="blue")
print crect.width, crect.height, crect.color
#3 5 blue
```

These two will refer to the same `Rectangle` object:

```
crect.width=10
print rect.width, rect.height
#10 5
```

This is an exellent talk on metaprogramming, and while it's title implies Python3 a lot of it also applies to python 2.x: *[David Beazley - Python3 Metaprogramming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI)*

---

### `getattr` hacking

If for any reason however, you would want to have multiple `ColoredRectangle` refer to the same base `Rectangle` then these will conflict with each other:

```
eve = Rectangle(3, 5)
kain = ColoredRectangle(eve, color="blue")
abel = ColoredRectangle(eve, color="red")
print eve.color, kain.color, abel.color
#red red red
```

If you'd like different *"proxy objects"*, which can get attributes from the base `Rectangle` but not interfere with each other, you **have** to resort to `getattr` hacking, which is fun too:

```
class ColoredRectangle(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, rect, color):
        self.rect = rect
        self.color = color
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.rect,attr)
eve = Rectangle(3, 5)
```

This will avoid the interference:

```
kain = ColoredRectangle(eve, color="blue")
abel = ColoredRectangle(eve, color="red")
print kain.color, abel.color
#blue red
```

About `__getattr__` versus `__getattribute__`:

> A key difference between **getattr** and **getattribute** is that
>   **getattr** is only invoked if the attribute wasn't found the usual ways. It's good for implementing a fallback for missing attributes,
>   and is probably the one of two you want. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute)

Because only non found attributes will be handled by `__getattr__` you can also partially update your proxies, which might be confusing:

```
kain.width=10
print eve.area(), kain.area(), abel.area()
# 15 50 15
```

To avoid this you can override `__setattr__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if attr == "color":
        return super(ColoredRectangle,self).setattr(attr,value)
    raise YourFavoriteException
```

Comment: awesome! I was just looking into `getattr` and `setattr` and wondering about  the class dictionary and how to use it. What's the difference between using `__dict__` and `__getattr__` and/or `__setattr__`? 
And thanks for the talk link. I'm always looking for good references.

Comment: It's three hours but Beazley is an amazing speaker. It's got the entire fun package: Regex, XML, `exec`, JIT code generation, import hacking, etc...

Comment: The `__dict__` example does not work if the `Rectangle` class defines `__slots__` or is written in C.

Comment: @SebastianWozny Am I not allowed to point out additional downsides. Not all python types have a\ `__dict__` attribute and expose **all their data** in it. In fact, the proxy `ColoredRectangle` is such a non-compliant type.

Comment: Why does forcing class dictionaries have the side effect you mention? Does the line `self.__dict__ = rect.__dict__` have the effect of setting the two dictionaries equal to each other in memory. So if you add one attribute to either dictionary you add it to both?

Answer (score 4):

What you seem to be asking to do is to redirect attribute accesses to the underlying `Rectangle` object. The `__getattr__` method can do this for you.

```
class ColoredRectangle(object):
  def __init__(self, rectangle, color):
      self.color = color
      self.rectangle = rectangle
  def __getattr__(self,attr):
       return getattr(self.rectangle,attr)
```

Comment: I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what that `rectangle` class attribute is for.

Comment: The reason for the `rectangle` class attribute is to server as a default, so that the `__setattr__` magic method knows that it being called from `__init__` and the class is still being initialized.

Comment: Sure, but information like that belongs in the answer itself, not just a comment. FWIW, I would've said something like "The `rectangle` class attribute forces `__setattr__` to call the default `object.__setattr__` when the instance attributes `.color` and `.rectangle` are being set during `__init__`, when there isn't yet a `.rectangle` instance attribute to re-direct  `__setattr__` calls to. And maybe you should also explicitly mention that if any new attributes are added to a `ColoredRectangle` instance they will actually get attached to the underlying `Rectangle` instance.

Comment: This behaviour seems like something I'd prefer to avoid. I shouldn't be able to change attributes of `Rectangle` from `ColoredRectangle`. Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: @Ben delete the `__setattr__` method and the `rectangle` class attribute from the `ColoredRectangle` class entirely, as I did in my recent edit.

Comment: Haha. I was just experimenting with removing `__setattr__` myself. Looks like it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben the term `access` is ambiguous. I interpreted it to mean get and set, while you only meant get.

Comment: @pperry. Ok. good to know for the future. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Owerwrite all attributes by rectangle attributes. They are in `__dict__` property.

```
import copy

class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, area):
        self.area = area

class ColoredRectangle(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, rectangle, color):
        self.__dict__ = copy.deepcopy(rectangle.__dict__)
        self.color = color
```

Comment: I was going for a simple example. Suppose there are many many attributes and methods corresponding to Rectangle. I don't want to overwrite them all.

Comment: @Ben then use `self.__dict__ = rectangle.__dict__`. I improve answer

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup. Then where would you put your `color` attribute?

Comment: @ppperry `self.color = color`?

Comment: That would also modify the raw rectangle's `.color` attribute.

Comment: @ppperry Look at Ben example. They overwrite color attribute

Comment: When you run this code with two `ColoredRectangles` with the same base Rectangle, the first one's color is lost.

Comment: @ppperry ok, You have right, but You can use copy.deepcopy to copy __dict__

Comment: The OP is trying to avoid creating copies of the base Rectangle instance, so creating deep copies of all its attributes in every ColoredRectangle instance is probably _not_ desirable. Also consider what happens if a Rectangle attribute is set via a ColoredRectangle.

Comment: Every copy constructor implementations on StackOverflow uses deepcopy. Then why my solution is bad? It's simple. It's pythonic.

Comment: This answer does not work if the `Rectangle` class defines `__slots__` or is written in C.