# Python subclass that doesn't inherit attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I'd like to create an Python class that superficially appears to be a subclass of another class, but doesn't actually inherit its attributes.

For instance, if my class is named `B`, I'd like `isinstance(B(), A)` to return `True`, as well as `issubclass(B, A)`, but I don't want `B` to have the attributes defined for A. Is this possible?

**Note**: I don't control the implementation of `A`.

**Why I care**: The module I'm working with checks that a passed object is a subclass of `A`. I want to define the necessary attributes in `B` without inheriting the superfluous attributes defined in `A` (whose implementation I do not control) because I'm using `__getattr__` to pass some attribute calls onto a wrapped class, and if these attributes are defined by inheritance from A, `__getattr__` won't be called.

Comment: You might want to look at abstract base classes. Also, do you target python 2 or 3?

Comment: Targeting Python 3.

Comment: Btw. this turned out to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141542). You should avoid asking to specifically for your single idea to solve your original problem and mention your original problem instead.

Comment: @poke Yeah, I realized that myself. Sorry 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python3, override the special method `__getattribute__`.  This gives you almost complete control over attribute lookups.  There are a few corner cases so check the docs carefully (it's section 3.3.2 of the Language Reference Manual).

Comment: Moreso than `__getattr__`? iirc, `__getattr__` won't be called if the attribute in question is already defined

Comment: `__getattribute__`, unlike `__getattr__`, gets called for all defined and undefined attributes

Comment: @LukeTaylor See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3278077/216074), `__getattribute__` is the hardcore way to stop access to members. That being said, this is not really a good solution, as you need to opt out of every member individually (and also prevent subtypes from actually redefining those members).

Comment: @LukeTaylor: The task at hand specifically requires the class B to inherit from A, yet override all the attributes that are already defined by A.  Hence the use of `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__` is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) to make a semingly unrelated class `B` a subclass of `A` without inheriting from it:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
class A (metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def foo (self):
        print('foo')

class B:
    def bar (self):
        print('bar')

A.register(B)
```

Then used, it gives the desired results and appears as a subtype without actually having any of the base type’s members:

```
>>> issubclass(B, A)
True
>>> b = B()
>>> isinstance(b, A)
True
>>> b.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    b.foo()
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

---

> I'm using `__getattr__` to pass some attribute calls onto a wrapped class, and if these attributes are defined by inheritance from `A`, `__getattr__` won't be called.

`__getattr__` is not invoked for members which are found using the normal attribute resolution. You can use `__getattribute__` then instead.

However, if what you are doing is overwriting the behavior of the base class `A`, then I don’t see why simply overwriting the methods is not an option:

```
class A:
    def doSomething (self);
        print('Do not do this!')

class B:
    def __init__ (self, wrapper):
        self.wrapper = wrapper

    def doSomething (self):
        print('Doing something else instead!')
        self.wrapper.doSomething()
```

Comment: A is already defined in a library which I don't control. Thanks, though

Answer (score 3):

You could implement `__getattribute__` to raise AttributeErrors for the attributes that are not in B:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

    def bar(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = 42

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr in ('foo', 'bar'):
            raise AttributeError()
        return super(B, self).__getattribute__(attr)
```

I'm curious, why would you do this?

Comment: I'm working with a library that checks whether something is a subclass before it will do anything with it, so I need to trick it into thinking that something with all the necessary methods (but not the superfluous ones) is a subclass when it's not.

Comment: @LukeTaylor In that case, why do you care whether those original members are actually there or not? If you are certain that they are not used (otherwise you couldn’t safely expect it to work without those members), then they probably won’t hurt anyone just *being* there.

Comment: @poke Because it _uses_ them, but I'm implementing `__getattr__` to read them from a wrapped class. If the methods are defined, `__getattr__` isn't called.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're defining attributes in the `__init__` method and you override that method, `B` will not run the code from `A`'s `__init__` and will thus not define attributes et al. Removing methods would be harder, but seem beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: `A` seems to be a thin wrapper around a C-implemented class, so overriding `__init__` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this satisfies you (I think it's a bit *dirty* hack):

```
class A:
    attribute = "Hello"
    pass

class B(A):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "__dict__":
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name in type(self).__dict__:
            return type(self).__dict__[name]
        if name in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[name]
        raise AttributeError("type object '{}' has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, name))
```

Now let's test it:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.attribute
'Hello'
>>> b = B()
>>> b.attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "file.py", line 13, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError("type object '{}' has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'attribute'
```

Unfortunately class `B` itself inherited attributes so this happens:

```
>>> B.attribute
'Hello'
```

I hope it doesn't matters, if it does you need to use metaclasses (which can get quite nasty).

Comment: Wait, how does this help? Your `__getattribute__` implementation doesn't look like it changes anything over the default behavior...

Comment: @LukeTaylor Paul Cornelius already answered how it works, I just gave example how to do it (not very practical, but good for example).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot ;)