# Python 3 __getattribute__ vs dot access behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, getattr, getattribute

I read a bit on [Python's object attribute lookup](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup):

Seems pretty straight forward, so I tried it out (python3):

```py
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return (1,2,3)

a = A()

a.foobar #returns (1,2,3) as expected
a.__getattribute__('foobar') # raises AttributeError
```

My question is, aren't the two supposed to be identical?

Why does the second one raise an attribute error?

So apparently the answer is that the logic for `a.foobar` IS different from the logic for `a.__getattribute("foobar")`. According to the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__): `a.foobar` calls `a.__getattribute("foobar")` and if it raises an AttributeError, it calls `a.-__getattr__('foobar')`

So it seems the article has a mistake in their diagram. Is this correct?

And another question: Where does the real logic for `a.foobar` sit? I thought it was in `__getattribute__` but apparently not entirely.

Edit:
**Not a duplicate of** [Difference between __getattr__ and __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute).

I am asking here what is the different between `object.foo` and `object.__getattribute__("foo")`.
This is different from `__getattr__` vs `__getatribute__` which is trivial...

Comment: Refer to official doc first: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Comment: Change `a.__getattribute__('foobar')` to `a.__getattr__('foobar')` and see what happens.

Comment: Not interested in that... `__getattribute__` is supposed to eventually call `__getattr__`.    `a.foobar` is supposed to call `__getattribute__`

Comment: Why? It doesn't exist so `__getattr__` is invoked instead.

Comment: @thodnev the data model spec is unclear. Does this mean that `a.foo` is implemented like this: 
`try
    a.__getattribute__
except AtributeError:
    a.__getattr__`
?

Comment: @dellar More or less. `__getattr__` is only tried if it exists, and there are special exceptions when magic methods are used. For instance, `len` bypasses both `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` to retrieve `__len__`.

Comment: @deller the `__getattribute__` is a decriptor, defined in one or more base classes (or in `object` if not elsewhere). By default it invokes `__getattr__` for unknown (not present in `__dict__` or nondefined as `__slots__` attrs). So usually you need to redefine `__getattr__` to intercept unknown attributes, and `__getattribute__` gives you total control (regulary not needed). Something like it

Comment: @thodnev: `__getattribute__` doesn't invoke `__getattr__`; the fallback to `__getattr__` is done separately. The fact that this is not `__getattribute__`'s responsibility is probably the source of the questioner's confusion.

Comment: @user2357112 _If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an AttributeError_

Comment: @user2357112 This is consistent with what i tried. Does this mean the diagram on the article is mistaken? it shows `__getattribute_`_calling `__getattr__`

Comment: @thodnev: That last bit about "or raises an AttributeError" is key. If `__getattribute__` raises an AttributeError, the attribute lookup process will try `__getattr__` next.

Comment: Where is all of this logic implemented? i thought `__getattribute__` was in charge of ALL the lookup process...

Comment: @user2357112 Do you guys believe this is a really a duplicate? Why was it marked as such? how can i remove the duplicate? i think its a legitimate question...

Comment: @vaultah please take a look. I do not think this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy to get the impression that `__getattribute__` is responsible for more than it really is. `thing.attr` doesn't directly translate to `thing.__getattribute__('attr')`, and `__getattribute__` is not responsible for calling `__getattr__`.

The fallback to `__getattr__` happens in the part of the attribute access machinery that lies outside `__getattribute__`. The attribute lookup process works like this:

- Find the `__getattribute__` method through a direct search of the object's type's [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), bypassing the regular attribute lookup process.
- Try `__getattribute__`.

  - If `__getattribute__` returned something, the attribute lookup process is complete, and that's the attribute value.
  - If `__getattribute__` raised a non-AttributeError, the attribute lookup process is complete, and the exception propagates out of the lookup.
  - Otherwise, `__getattribute__` raised an AttributeError. The lookup continues.
- Find the `__getattr__` method the same way we found `__getattribute__`.

  - If there is no `__getattr__`, the attribute lookup process is complete, and the AttributeError from `__getattribute__` propagates.
- Try `__getattr__`, and return or raise whatever `__getattr__` returns or raises.

At least, in terms of the language semantics, it works like that. In terms of the low-level implementation, some of these steps may be optimized out in cases where they're unnecessary, and there are C hooks like `tp_getattro` that I haven't described. You don't need to worry about that kind of thing unless you want to dive into the CPython interpreter source code.

Comment: TL;DR `__getattribute__` bypasses the regular attribute lookup only if it is defined and is not intended to call `__getattr__`. Calling `__getattribute__` directly on a class which does not define it, falls back to `object.__getattribute__` or another base class and thus raises (probably) an `AttributeError`