# How did i access class methods via a variable which name as same as a method?

Tags: python

Sometimes I don't know what will be operated by user.

```
class User(object):
    ...

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

operation = "http://localhost:8080/user/get_name".split('/')[-1]
user = User(...)
```

As you see, the `operation` is a variable name is as same as the class attribute.

I try:

```
eval('user.{}'.format(operation))
```

It can run. But it looks very appropriate

Now I want to handle it via a way like `user.operation`

How did I achieve it ?

Comment: `user.__getattribute__(operation)`

Comment: Side-note: Python frowns on `get_x` functions. Either allow direct access to the attributes (if they're supposed to be mutable), or name the attribute `_name` (to indicate implementation details) and made an `@property` function named `name`, so you can access via `user.name` without needing parens.

Comment: In fact, if my class `Foo` has a attribute named `get_name()`, mybey i will get a variable `test` which value is `get_name`, so i want to execute it via `f = Foo() f.test()`. Perhaps this is not very clear expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getattr()`. Apply like so:

```
getattr(user, operation)()
```

So now, the `User` instance, `user` will call `operation` from a string.

`getattr` will get the attribute of an object, `user` in this case. Then it will do `user.operation`, then execute with `()`.

Try it on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/uOaCBi)

Comment: Calling `__getattribute__` manually doesn't work quite as well as it might initally seem, because [if you call `__getattribute__` manually, you won't get the `__getattr__` fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043912/python-3-getattribute-vs-dot-access-behaviour). Also, `foo.__getattribute__` does something different when `foo` is a class than when `foo` isn't a class.

Comment: @user2357112 You're correct, should I edit my answer to exclude `__getattribute__`?

Comment: I'd leave out `__getattribute__`. `getattr` fits the general-purpose "get attribute value from attribute name string" job much better. It's rare that you'd want to call `__getattribute__` unless you're overriding it.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok, thanks for the advice!