# How is the `__getattribute__` method involved in the lookup procedures?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python in a Nutshell describes:

- the lookup procedure when getting an attribute from a class, e.g. `cls.name` (see the first part in [Why are the lookup procedures for getting an attribute from a class and from an instance different?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44938264/156458))
- [the lookup procedure when getting an attribute from an instance, e.g. `obj.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913505/look-up-an-attribute-from-an-instance)

How is the `__getattribute__` method involved in the above lookup procedures?

- Is the `__getattribute__` method called somewhere in the lookup procedures?
- Or, are the lookup procedures started by calling `__getattribute__`, which then does all the work in the two links?

Thanks.

Comment: With all these attribute lookup questions you've been asking, I figured you'd want to hear about this part eventually.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043912/python-3-getattribute-vs-dot-access-behaviour), though with a focus on different details than the ones you're looking at.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Attribute lookup starts with calling `__getattribute__` and it does all the work mentioned in the links. Based on the type of the object either `object.__getattribute__` or `type.__getattribute__` is called.

---

Any attribute lookup results in `LOAD_ATTR` bytecode internally.

```
>>> import dis    
>>> dis.dis(lambda: foo.x)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (x)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

[`LOAD_ATTR`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L2796) then calls [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr).

`PyObject_GetAttr` now looks for either [`tp_getattro`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) or [`tp_getattr`(deprecated)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattr) slot on the object's type.

```
PyObject *

PyObject_GetAttr(PyObject *v, PyObject *name)
{
    PyTypeObject *tp = Py_TYPE(v);
    ...
    if (tp->tp_getattro != NULL)
        return (*tp->tp_getattro)(v, name);
    if (tp->tp_getattr != NULL) {
        const char *name_str = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(name);
        if (name_str == NULL)
            return NULL;
        return (*tp->tp_getattr)(v, (char *)name_str);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now if an object has its own implementation of `__getattribute__` then that is used else it falls back to  either `object.__getattribute__` or `type.__getattribute__` based on the type. [`tp_getattro` slot](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L4605) in case of `object` points to [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1207) and for [`type`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3438) it points to [`type_getattro`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3033).

`PyObject_GenericGetAttr` and `type_getattro` basically do all the work of checking for descriptors, dictionary, slots etc(based on the type) and try to return a value. If they fail to find it even after everything then `AttributeError` is raised and if the object's type defined `__getattr__` then it will be invoked.