# Is there a reason why Python has both __getattr__ and __getattribute__

Tags: python, attributes

I'm aware that the methods `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` do not do the same thing; the former is responsible for all attribute access and the latter, if defined, is called when the former raises AttributeError.

What puzzles me is why two similarly named methods related to attribute access even exist for a language that usually tries to eliminate confusion. I can't even think of a situation where I would HAVE to define a `__getattr__`; I can just define a `__getattribute__` that uses `object.__getattribute__` in an if statement or try statement. Moreover, the built-in function for attribute access is named `getattr` which would mislead people into thinking `__getattr__` is the go-to method for attribute access. What's the history behind these two methods and is there a good reason they both still exist?

Comment: `__getattr__` came first. It wasn't good enough, so they added `__getattribute__` to cover the cases `__getattr__` couldn't handle, but they had to keep `__getattr__` for backward compatibility.

Comment: This is a common question and answered thoroughly at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute

Comment: @Deepstop: That answers what the difference is, not why both of these things exist.

Comment: why didn't they just update `__getattr__` instead of making a `__getattribute__`

Comment: Backward compatibility.

Comment: It's not just backwards compatibility. `__getattr__` is a lot easier to use when applicable. It's also possible to use both in the same class.

Comment: an example illustrating how `__getattr__` is easier or more efficient than a `__getattribute__` with a try statement would be nice a.k.a. an accepted answer