# Is there a way I can create a custom dictionary in python without copy method?

Tags: python

I am having a use case where I want to store a key value pair in dictionary.
The problem I'm facing is my key is 'copy'. So after inserting 'copy' key, I'm not able to access it via getattr method, since it always returns the copy method of dict.

I cannot use get method on dict because my code is unaware of the type of object that is being passed. So, I went ahead with using getattr which is generic function to access properties.

I also created a custom class inheriting from dict and wrote **getattribute** but that blocks access to methods

```py
class DictLike(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, k):
        try:
            return self[k]
        except KeyError:
            getattr(super(DictLike, self), k)

    def paste(self):
        return "Test"



a = DictLike()
a['copy'] = 1;
a['state'] = 'completed'

print(getattr(a, 'copy')) // prints 1
print(a.paste()) // this does not works
```

```py
b = {'copy': 1}

print(b.get('copy')) \\ 1
getattr(b, 'copy') \\ function
```

Is there a way I could fix this behavior ?

Comment: Why on earth would you use `getattr()` on a `dict` to retrieve the value associated with a key ??? `getattr()` is for __attributes__ access, not for  subscripting. `getattr()` will NEVER return the value for a key of a dict.

Comment: "I cannot use get method on dict because my code is unaware of the type of object that is being passed." => please explain what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: "So, I went ahead with using getattr which is generic function to access properties" => dict keys are NOT properties.

Comment: typical XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please explain your __real__ problem (=> " cannot use get method on dict because my code is unaware of the type of object that is being passed.") instead.

Comment: are you aware that you can just do `print(a['copy'])` to print the value of the item corresponding to the 'copy' key ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I am trying to read a file which has a column 'copy'. DictLike object is one container in a strategy to read this file.There are other strategies also which read other files into other custom objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
class DictLike(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(DictLike, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.itemlist = super(DictLike, self).keys()

    def __getattribute__(self, k):
        try:
            return self[k]
        except Exception as e:
            return super().__getattribute__ (k)

    def paste(self):
        return "Test"


a = DictLike()
a['copy'] = 1
a['state'] = 'completed'

print(getattr(a, 'copy'))
print(a.paste())
```

Comment: how does this line 'super().__getattribute__ (k)' not causes infinite recursion

Comment: We are calling the super().__getattribute__ (k) just once, it wont invoke the child method again and again.

Comment: but the paste method is defined on child object. Isn't __getattribute__ called everytime, my concern is how did it got to paste method

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if you define `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`.

Comment: Re-read the question more carefully. The root problem is that the OP seems to be thinking that `getattr(d, somekey)` works the same as `d[somekey]`.

Comment: I understood that the problem was the call to `a.paste()` not working, using `__getattr__` fixes that.

Comment: As I said, re-read the WHOLE post. This is typically a XY problem (cf the "I cannot use get method on dict because my code is unaware of the type of object that is being passed. So, I went ahead with using getattr" part).

Answer (score 0):

You're right you wont be able to use getattr to get the key named "copy". As I feel like you might know, Python PEP standards suggest changing the name for keywords if there is conflicting namespaces. However, yours isn't a keyword, I'd still follow this standard. Current standard is trailing underscore such as "copy_". Stated [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) in PEP8 standards: "single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword."

I'm confused what you mean by dictVar.get() can't access your key because its unaware of the type. What other type are you passing. it works for strings or ints for certain.

Comment: `getattr` will not get the key named "copy_" either (on a dict I mean).

Comment: Yessir, I understand that. I didn't suggest that to him. I said he would not be able to access the key "copy" with `getattr`. I suggest he rename his key to "copy_". This can therefore accessed by `myDict.get("copy_")` with no confusion (even though `myDict.get("copy")` also works). EDIT: I see where my wording could have been poor. But, for the record I am not suggesting to use getattr to get a key's value.

Answer (score -1):

You should use **getattr**, here's a good explanation - [Difference between __getattr__ vs __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute)

So, it works perfectly:

```
class DictLike(dict):                                                                                                      
    def __getattr__(self, k):                                                                                              
        try:                                                                                                               
            return self[k]                                                                                                 
        except KeyError:                                                                                                   
            getattr(super(DictLike, self), k)                                                                              

    def paste(self):                                                                                                       
        return "Test"                                                                                                      


a = DictLike()                                                                                                             
a['copy'] = 1;                                                                                                             
a['state'] = 'completed'                                                                                                   

print(a['copy'])                                                                                                           
print(a.paste())
```

And the output is:

```
1
Test
```

Comment: Re-read the question more carefully. The root problem is that the OP seems to be thinking that `getattr(d, somekey)` works the same as `d[somekey]`.