# Why is __getattr__catching also existing attributes?

Tags: python, class, getattr

I created this class to test some of the `__getattr__` features:

```
class Trace:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        print('set ' + attr)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print('get ' + attr)
```

I then created an instance

```
a = Trace(10)
print(a.val)
a.val = 5
print(a.val)
```

But, even if I fetched only existing attributes, this was the output:

```
set val
get val
None
set val
get val
None
```

I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: That’s what getattr and setattr do. What were you expecting, and why?

Comment: @barny well, I suppose since `self.val` was already defined you would [expect `__getattr__` to never be invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute).

Comment: Except `self.val` never *was* defined; `__setattr__` has to actually make the assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__getattr__` is only called when an attribute isn’t found normally, but `__setattr__` has no such restriction (that’s why there’s no equivalent of `__getattribute__` for it). You overrode `__setattr__` to not actually set an instance attribute, so the attribute is always missing and `__getattr__` is called anyway. (Yes, it applies in `__init__` too.)

Remove `__setattr__` to see your expected behaviour quickly, or add its default behaviour back:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    print('set ' + attr)
    super().__setattr__(attr, value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this explanation was really useful!