# Defining a __getattr__ fallback

Tags: python

If I have the following class:

```
class Item:
    def __getattribute__(self, a):
        return super().__getattribute__(a)
    def __getattr__(self, a):
        print ("Calling the second one (AttributeError on __getattribute__)!")
```

Now if I do something like:

```
i=Item()
i.x
```

It will hit an `AttributeError` in `__getattribute__` and fall back to `__getattr__`. What is the point of having such a fallback? For example, why couldn't someone just customize the `__getattribute__` method itself if an `AttributeError` is reached? What would be a legitimate use case of defining a `__getattr__` / `__getattribute__` pair?

Comment: This is truly strange, behaviour although possibly a duplication of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way it is for historical reasons. `__getattr__` was the only method of the two to exist in the obsolete "old-style" class system. `__getattribute__` came later, but they couldn't take out `__getattr__`, because it would have broken a lot of code, as well as causing problems for mixing the old-style and new-style class systems.

It's slightly more convenient to be able to define a `__getattr__` instead of overriding `__getattribute__` when you want your logic to be a fallback for the default logic, but it's extremely unlikely that that would have been enough to motivate the inclusion of `__getattr__` in the language if `__getattribute__` had existed from the start.