# How does __getattribute__ fetch a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, built-in

```
class test():
  name = 'arthur'

  def __getattribute__(self, value):
    return super().__getattribute__(value)

x = test()
x.name

------------------------------------------
Output: 'arthur'
```

I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanism of `__getattribute__`. I understand (hopefully) that `super().__getattribute__(value)` reaches out to the object class in this case. But how actually does `object` fetch the `name` value out of the test() class? And how could one fetch an attribute value with `__getattribute__` if coded in a class by oneself while avoiding recursion?

As I said, I want to understand the underlying mechanisms, I know this isn't the way how you would usually handle things.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute

Comment: I read that thread before, none of the answers answer my specific question, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `__getattribute__` is a magic method (aka `dunder` method/double underscore method). This is a property/attribute accessor method and it intercepts on every property/attribute access even if the property/attribute is available in the class itself. On the other hand, the `__getattr__` magic method is called only if the property you are accessing doesn't exist in the class/instance. Anyways...

There is also one more important thing to notice that, as you might already know that, all classes extends/inherits the base `object` class implicitly or explicitly. So, any class you define, the default parent class is the built-in `object` class. You are confused as you asked:

> I understand (hopefully) that `super().__getattribute__(value)` reaches
>   out to the `object` class in this case. But how actually does `object`
>   fetch the `name` value out of the `test()` class?

So lets see some basic examples first:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

So, when you call

```
object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

You are passing the context (an instance of the class) explicitly to the parent (`object`) class. so the parent/object class knows the context and get the attribute from that passed instance. On the other hand, when you call:

```
super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Python sets the context for you. So, you can imagine something like this:

```
super(test, self).__getattribute__(name) # it's valid
```

But in this case, it's implicit, that's how the `super()` call knows where to lookup for the attribute. It's worth mentioning that, Python's `super()` builtin function returns a proxy [object](https://appdividend.com/2019/01/11/python-object-oriented-programming-tutorial-with-example/), a substitute object that can call the method of the base class via delegation and also `super()` can take two parameters (as you've seen in previous code snippet), the first is the subclass type (in this case `test`), and the second parameter is an object, an instance of that subclass (`test`).

In `Python 3`, the `super(test, self)` call is equivalent to the parameterless `super()` call. Hope I've clarified your confusions. You may read more about [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super).

Answer (score 2):

You can’t code this in Python. It’s a C function that Python calls:

```
PyObject *
PyObject_GetAttr(PyObject *v, PyObject *name)
{
    PyTypeObject *tp = Py_TYPE(v);

    if (!PyUnicode_Check(name)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "attribute name must be string, not '%.200s'",
                     name->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (tp->tp_getattro != NULL)
        return (*tp->tp_getattro)(v, name);
    if (tp->tp_getattr != NULL) {
        const char *name_str = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(name);
        if (name_str == NULL)
            return NULL;
        return (*tp->tp_getattr)(v, (char *)name_str);
    }
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_AttributeError,
                 "'%.50s' object has no attribute '%U'",
                 tp->tp_name, name);
    return NULL;
}
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8289e27393395ee903bd096d42e07c112d7f15c6/Objects/object.c#L1001-L1024

This is `object.__getattribute__`. It’s called in your example because all classes inherit from `object`.

Comment: So just to make sure that I understand it correctly, when ```super()__getattribute__(value)``` reaches object, object calls an internal C-function named ```builtin_getatrr``` which searches for the desired value via inheritance search while somehow avoiding to trigger ```__getattribute__``` again?
( I don't understand the C code that's why I ask)

Comment: @Arthred Updated. The last code was for `getattr` which was maybe why it was confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I need to understand how ```object.__getattribute__``` avoids ending up in a recursive loop and actually manages to fetch the desired value?

Comment: Because until now everywhere I've read we need to call ```object.__getattribute``` because otherwise we end up in a loop and I would love to know how object actually avoids that

Comment: @Arthred You’re welcome. You’re using `super()` which is `object` not `test`. There is no recursion.

Comment: Maybe my question is just really poorly articulated or my question is just dumb. But I was wondering, how does ```object.__getattribute__``` return the attribute? Because when it calls let's say ```x.name``` it would invoke ```test.__getattribute``` again which in turn would call ```object.__getattribute__``` again. Obviously this doesn't happen, but how does ```object.__getattribute__``` access the ```name``` attribute of ```test``` without calling the method again then? @Anonymous

Comment: @Arthred I think I see where you’re confused. Python doesn’t need to call `__getattr__`. It knows all the attributes on an object. That’s only called when you get an attribute from Python code.