# Mock class returning same value for all attributes

Tags: python, mocking

I want to mock a class and for any attribute it should return the same string.

```
c = SomeMocking(all_attributes="abc")
c.foo == "abc"
True
c.bar == "abc"
True
```

Should https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html do the trick? I only find `return_value` which can be used for function calls and not for arbitrary attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is too simple. But this would always return the same value for every attribute:

```py
class A:
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return 'abc'

print(A().foo)
```

If you also want to have your own attributes in the class and only have this used for undefined ones, you should use `__getattr__`. You can read about the difference in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute).

These special methods simply mimic the access to an attribute with the name give in the `name` parameter.