# Inheriting from defaultddict and OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have tried inheriting from both [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) like so:

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(defaultdict, OrderedDict): pass
```

and like so:

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict, defaultdict): pass
```

in order to created an ordered default dict (a class that should remember the order in which new default items were generated) but it seems to throw an error stating:

```
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309129/1658617) that it's because they're both implemented in C. Upon disabling Python's C implementation of `OrderedDict` by commenting this section in the `collections` module:

```
try:
    from _collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    # Leave the pure Python version in place.
    pass
```

I have managed to inherit from both, but it does not seem to work as I expected. I have two questions then:

1. **Why can't you inherit from two classes written in C?** I would understand if you wouldn't be able to inherit from any class written in C but why can you inherit from one and not from 2?
2. Implementing my requested class would be easy by subclassing `OrderedDict` and overriding `__getitem__()` to match `defaultdict`'s behavior. **Is there a better way (preferably within the standard library) to mimick the same behavior?** Or is subclassing `OrderedDict` the most optimal? (subclassing `defaultdict` is possible too but implementing it is is probably easier using `OrderedDict`)

**The first question is the important of the two** as implementing it myself by subclassing `OrderedDict` shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: I think you'd be better off subclassing `OrderedDict` and defining a [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) method.

Comment: I think if your edit is true wrt what "the important part" of your question is, then it's a duplicate. You've misread the answer you linked. The point isn't that they're implemented in C. The point is that they're internally incompatible (though the C implementation makes that more possible/likely) so there's no way for Python to automatically use them for multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Why would they be internally incompatible? Classes in the STL usually talk with themselves nicely like `OrderedDict` and `Counter` for example.

Comment: That's a better question for the Python mailing list than for me. Wild guess: they're both subsets of dict written in C and no effort was made to give them a similar API because they're not similar in function.

Comment: See the `OrderedDefaultdict` class in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4127426/355230).

Answer (score 4):

The functionality of `defaultdict` can be simply implemented by defining a `__missing__` method:

```
class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, **kwargs):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __missing__(self, key):
        result = self[key] = self.default_factory()
        return result
```

Comment: I think I'd want to make the `__init__` a little more robust than this. You're losing a lot of `dict` functionality this way.

Comment: agreed. just use the `__init__` from defaultdict: `def __init__(self, default_factory=None, **kwargs):`

Comment: @acushner: agreed.

Comment: @Daniel just on a side note, it's always funny when people use `**kwargs` with an `OrderedDict`, because those `kwargs` themselves aren't necessarily in any particular order. but it is still usable. nice update to the answer.